# zsh: What glob expression is equivalent to `find . -type f`?

Tags: zsh, wildcards

I'm looking for the simplest glob expression that will *always* expand to the same (possibly empty) set of files as that listed by

```
find . -type f
```

...and never result in a `no matches found` error, irrespective of the contents of `.`.

I've tried many variations of `./{**,.**}/{*,.*}(.N)` that fail under one situation or another.  (For example, `./{**,.**}/{*,.*}(.N)` fails to match `./.dir0/.dir1/.file0`.)

EDIT: Assume that `extendedglob` is `on`, and that `nullglob` is `off`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
print -rl -- ./**/*(.DoN)
```

Comment: That's great.  Thank you.  What why not `**/*(.DN)`?

Comment: @kjo: yes, realize it recently, edited.

Comment: Strictly speaking, that would be more like `./**/*(.DoN)` to add the `./` prefix to each file and not sort the files (`find` internally may sort by inode number to optimise performance on rotational storage, so you may still find differences in the order). If there's no matching file with the `N` flag, `print` will still print an empty line. You may want to omit that flag which makes for a more pertinent outcome in that case.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Fair point, updated.